# aws kinesis put_record issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-kinesis

I am using aws_cli command to send events to kinesis data stream but having some issues while putting record into kinesis stream

**commands**

```
USER_ID="3456"
```

```
input_data={"user_id": $USER_ID,"name":"siva","qulification":"degree","age":"27","location":"canada"}
```

```
aws kinesis put-record --stream-name b-in-stream  --partition-key 999 --data input_data
```

**Note:**
USER_ID ==> its value is dynamic.

I used these commands on linux terminal but somehow `aws-kinesis put-record` is not working.

**Can anyone suggest a solution how to use kinesis put-record with a variable in the data field?**

Comment: "aws-kinesis put-record is not working." - is not specific. Why exactly it does not work? What happens? Any error messages?

Comment: no error message but `aws-kinesis put-record` is not inserting data into `kinesis datastream`

Comment: `USER_ID` is a variable and how to use this variable in the  `--data` section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `bash` in linux, your commands are incorrect. Your input data should be:

```
USER_ID="3456"

input_data='{"user_id": '$USER_ID',"name":"siva","qulification":"degree","age":"27","location":"canada"}'
```

Then, in the command you should use `"${input_data}"`, not `input_data`:

```
aws kinesis put-record --stream-name b-in-stream --partition-key 999 --data "${input_data}"
```